# How to print non-ASCII characters in Python

Tags: python, extended-ascii

I have a problem when I'm printing (or writing to a file) the non-ASCII characters in Python. I've resolved it by overriding the `str` method in my own objects, and making "x.encode('utf-8')" inside it, where x is a property inside the object.

But, if I receive a third-party object, and I make "str(object)", and this object has a non-ASCII character inside, it will fail.

So the question is: is there any way to tell the `str` method that the object has an UTF-8 codification, generically? I'm working with Python 2.5.4.

Comment: What does "receive a a third-party object" mean?  What third-party object?  And why can't this mysterious object be trusted to produce proper string values?

Comment: I'm interacting with other programs which are not made by me. Those programs can have objects with string properties which can contain non-ascii characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to say that I've found a solution in Unix systems, exporting a environment var, with this:

export LC_CTYPE="es:ES.UTF-8"

This way, all files are in utf-8, so I can make prints or whatever and it works fine

Comment: What does this have to do with your question? Or with python?

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to make `str()` work with Unicode in Python < 3.0.

Use `repr(obj)` instead of `str(obj)`. `repr()` will convert the result to ASCII, properly escaping everything that isn't in the ASCII code range.

Other than that, use a file object which allows unicode. So don't encode at the input side but at the output side:

```
fileObj = codecs.open( "someFile", "w", "utf-8" )
```

Now you can write unicode strings to `fileObj` and they will be converted as needed. To make the same happen with `print`, you need to wrap `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys, codecs, locale
print str(sys.stdout.encoding)
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout)
line = u"\u0411\n"
print type(line), len(line)
sys.stdout.write(line)
print line
```

Comment: But I have the same problem when I use print(object), because internally it calls to str, so if the object has a non-ascii character it will fail.

I've seen that I can put this in the first line of my files.py:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
but it doesn't work

Comment: The encoding of the source file has nothing to do with what `str()` supports. `str()` only supports unicode characters in py3k, so either use repr() or unicode() everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

```
none_ascii = '''
        ███╗   ███╗ ██████╗ ██╗   ██╗██╗███████╗███████╗ 
        ████╗ ████║██╔═══██╗██║   ██║██║██╔════╝██╔════╝ 
        ██╔████╔██║██║   ██║██║   ██║██║█████╗  ███████╗ 
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██║   ██║╚██╗ ██╔╝██║██╔══╝  ╚════██║ 
        ██║ ╚═╝ ██║╚██████╔╝ ╚████╔╝ ██║███████╗███████║ 
        ╚═╝     ╚═╝ ╚═════╝   ╚═══╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝ 
'''

print(none_ascii.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about you use `unicode(object)` and define `__unicode__` method on your classes?

Then you know its unicode and you can encode it anyway you want into to a file.

Comment: But then I'm in the same problem: if I receive a third party object and I use "unicode(object)", and the object has a non-ascii character, it will fail, won't it?

Comment: Besides, when I use "print(object)", internally it calls str method, so I can't use unicode

Comment: One more question: if I use python 3, Won't I have those problems? Python3 makes the conversion alone? Does it accept non-ascii characters by default?

Comment: All Python 3 strings are (what used to be) unicode by default.

Comment: First, please realize, if you receive and array of bytes, witch python strings essetialy are, there is no way to be sure what encoding it is in. If there are third-party objects that give you strings in non-standard encoding, they should also provide which encoding it is in.

Answer (score 0):

just paste these two lines at the top of your code

1. #!/usr/local/bin/python
2. # coding: latin-1

go to this link for further details **https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/**